# Correct graphQL syntax for a list of strings

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

This is a fragment of a JSON object I receive from an http response.
[image]

How does one code the corresponding "networks" field in the GraphQLObjectType?  here is the associated (and working!) definition.
[image]

I appreciate any and all help.  I am new to GraphQL, but tried to solve the question myself.  The answer was elusive, as all the examples I came across had to do with lists that referenced other nodes of the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GraphQLList` wrapper can be used to indicate arrays of objects (`GraphQLObjectType`) or scalars like `GraphQLString`, `GraphQLInt`, `GraphQLBoolean`, etc. That means you can just do:

```
networks: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString) }
```

Note that unlike declaring a normal type or scalar, when using `GraphQLList` (or `GraphQLNonNull`) you have to call its constructor using the `new` keyword.